# Flag the first time an ID from one column appears in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
 ID1 ID2 Date
 1   2   01/01/2018
 1   2   03/01/2018
 1   2   04/05/2018
 2   1   06/06/2018
 1   2   08/06/2018
 3   4   09/07/2018
```

etc.

What I need to do is to flag the first time that an ID in ID1 appears in ID2. In the above example this would look like

```
ID1 ID2 Date         Flag
 1   2   01/01/2018
 1   2   03/01/2018
 1   2   04/05/2018
 2   1   06/06/2018
 1   2   08/06/2018  Y
 3   4   09/07/2018
```

I've used the following code to tell me if ID1 ever occurs in ID2:

```
ID2List= df['ID2'].tolist()
ID2List= list(set(IDList))  # dedupe list
df['ID1 is in ID2List'] = np.where(df[ID1].isin(ID2List), 'Yes', 'No')
```

But this only tells me that there is an occasion where ID1 appears in ID2 at some point but not the event at which this first occurs.

Any help?

Comment: Shouldn't the `Y` be one row above, where `1` first occurs in `ID2`?

Comment: Graipher - yes you are right!

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use `next` with a generator expression to calculate the indices of matches in `ID1`. Then compare with index and use `argmax` to get the index of the first `True` value:

```
idx = df.apply(lambda row: next((idx for idx, val in enumerate(df['ID1']) \
                                 if row['ID2'] == val), 0), axis=1)

df.loc[(df.index > idx).argmax(), 'Flag'] = 'Y'

print(df)

   ID1  ID2        Date Flag
0    1    2  01/01/2018  NaN
1    1    2  03/01/2018  NaN
2    1    2  04/05/2018  NaN
3    2    1  06/06/2018    Y
4    1    2  08/06/2018  NaN
5    3    4  09/07/2018  NaN
```